# Checking if database value is greater than local value in Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I think this is simple but can't seem to create the correct query. I'm using Swift with Firebase Realtime Database on iOS.

Consider the following Firebase structure:

```
-DATA
--UID
---LEVEL1
----HIGHSCORE
```

I am trying to create a query to find out whether the specific HIGHSCORE number for a level is greater than a local variable. If it is, I want the return to be the higher value from Firebase. If it is the same or lower, I want the return to be null.

I have tried many different queries, here is an example:

```
ref.child("DATA/UID/LEVEL1/HIGHSCORE").queryStarting(atValue: 5000).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with:
```

I know this is fundamentally incorrect, but I think it shows what I am trying to do.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Mike

EDIT: Here is the actual JSON example:

```
{
 "DATA" : {
    "USERID" : {
      "LEVEL1" : {
        "HIGHSCORE" : 5000,
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you want to read highscore?

Comment: It is more likely we can help if you share the actual JSON (as text, no screenshots), instead of a mock. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Also make sure that your use-case is clear. I see a few options here. 1) Are you trying to read the highscore for a known user on a known level? 2) Are you trying to *find* the level with the highest score for a known user? 3) Are you trying to find the highest score across all users for a known level? 4) Are you trying to find the highest score across all users across all levels?

Comment: Sorry, I realize not including the JSON makes it a bit vague. My use-case is such: I am checking if the user's score in Firebase is higher than their score locally; if it is higher, I want to return the score and update the local client; if it is not higher, I do not want to return anything. I am trying to do the check server-side so as not to incur charges on returning the value and comparing it client-side. Happy to know if my approach is incorrect in this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This would be a check for a score for a known user on a known level.

Comment: @frankvanpuffelen I forgot to @ you, so you probably didn't see my replies. I hope what I wrote was clear. Thanks again for your help, much appreciated!

Comment: @excitedmicrobe I want to read the specific high score, but only return the value if it's higher than the value I pass in. I hope that makes sense. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think of is with an `orderByValue`:

```
ref.child("DATA/UID/LEVEL1").orderByValue().queryStarting(atValue: 5000).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with:
```

But this only works well if `HIGHSCORE` is the only child node under `LEVEL1`. Even then: it doesn't have any bandwidth or performance over the more idiomatic approach:

```
ref.child("DATA/UID/LEVEL1/HIGHSCORE").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in 
  if snapshot.exists() {
    val score = snapshot.value as! Int
    if score > 5000 {
      ...
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: OK, this makes sense and I see what I was missing. Wouldn't the way I'm suggesting cost less though since if the score was not higher in Firebase, it would just return null, therefore not incurring any cost? Compared to returning the value each time and comparing on the client, since that would incur a charge each time - albeit, a small one? Thanks again for your help, @frankvanpuffelen.

Comment: In the one case you're sending the value from the client to the server and not getting a result. In the other case you're not sending a value from the client to the server, but are getting a result. So in both cases there is only one value on the wire. To be honest, even if there was a different it'd be negligible and a typical case of [premature optimization](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization).